# sharepoint 2010 with silverlight 4 webpart

Tags: sharepoint-server, silverlight

I need to display list data in silverlight datagrid (which i managed to do) but i can't figure out how to display item details in another xaml page.
like example : Display all List items

[image]

and on view details button

[image]

how to get this done is silverlight webpart ?
i am very new to silverlight application development Hope some one could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my Solution by adding refrence in mainpage.xaml `xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation` and a frame used navigationServices.navigate properly.